# Using ggplot to draw straight lines that might or might not be horizontal or vertical

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot I want to plot straight lines of the form ax + by + c = 0, where the three parameters are generated by my code. If neither a nor b are zero, ggplot requires me to use `geom_abline` but if a = 0 or b = 0, I'd need to use `geom_vline` or `geom_hline` respectively.

It is messy to have to test a=0 and b=0 to select the right geom. What I'd really like is a geom like this:

`geom_line(x_param = a, y_param = b, const = c)`

but it does not seem to exist.

Is there a non-messy solution to my problem?

Comment: Write your own wrapper function to choose the right geom. It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some data and test cases that could be used to test possible solutions.

Comment: You can use `geom_abline` with `slope=0` (i.e `a=0`), but it certainly objects to `slope=Inf` (`b=0`). An alternative for a general solution would be to use `geom_segment` where you specify the ends of the line.

Comment: @MrFlick The wrapper function option is what I consider to be messy.

Comment: @AndrewGustar I had forgotten that slope = 0 works with abline. That makes the wrapper function a bit less messy.

Comment: What is your definition of "messy". Functions are meant to hide complexity.

Comment: Agreed that is the purpose of functions but the functions themselves can be very complex. Maybe 'inelegant' is the word.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to help without some example data, but suppose you had parameters in a data frame like this:

```
df.params <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 0, 1, .3),
  b = c(1, .27, 0, 0),
  c = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
)

    a    b c
1 0.0 1.00 1
2 0.0 0.27 2
3 1.0 0.00 3
4 0.3 0.00 4
```

From this, you could use a single call to `geom_segment` to draw vertical or horizontal lines using `Inf` values. You can use `ifelse` to test for zeros in your parameters and swap in either `Inf`s or your intercept values for each line:

```
ggplot(data = df.params) +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x =    ifelse(a == 0, -Inf, c),
    xend = ifelse(a == 0, Inf, c),
    y =    ifelse(b == 0, -Inf, c),
    yend = ifelse(b == 0, Inf, c)
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the wrapper function that I wrote follwoing the very helpful comments given.  In my opinion it is not too inelegant.

```
line <- function(a, b, c) { 
  if (a == 0 & b == 0) {
    warning('Invalid parameters for line') 
   } else if (b == 0) {
    geom <- geom_vline(xintercept = -c / a) 
   } else {
    geom <- geom_abline(intercept = -c / b, slope = -a / b) 
   }
  return(geom) 
}
```